# I have a really slow function and I am thinking of splitting the data into a a list of 10 and process , but I am not sure what to use to solve this

Tags: javascript, python, html, pandas, flask

I am solving this problem using dataframes and .apply and It is taking forever for it run for 437 values. The advice I got is:

Display 10 on HTML first, and then in the background run the program for the rest in groupings of 10 values, and every time it finishes processing the data, I send it back to the HTML from Flask and then repeat this until all the data is available. But I have literally no clue about what I should search on how to solve my problem or even what I should use. Any Idea on how I should go about this?

```
def get_project_details(pids: list, conn: pymssql._pymssql.Connection) -> dict:
pidq = ",".join([f"'{x}'" for x in pids])
query = f"SELECT * FROM VW_CSMS_PMT_ProjectDetails WHERE Project_Id in ({pidq})"
df = pd.read_sql(
    query,
    con=conn,
    parse_dates=["StartDate", "TargetDate"],
)
out = df.apply(
    lambda x: {
        "id": x["Project_Id"],
        "type": "project",
        "name": x["Project_Name"],
        "start_date": get_date_string(x["StartDate"]),
        "target_date": get_date_string(x["TargetDate"]),
        "estimate": x["EST_HRS"],
        "status": x["status"],
        "timesheet_details": tdp(x["Project_Id"], conn),
        "main_task": get_main_task(x["Project_Id"], conn),
    },
    axis=1,
)

if isinstance(out, pd.core.series.Series):
    out = out.tolist()
else:
    out = None
return out
```

Comment: Please, add you code so we can help you better.

Comment: How are you cleaning your SQL input?

Comment: @ifly6 Is it necessary? I think I am doing that in df.apply function

Comment: My comment about the cleaning for the SQL input is that your project seems to be related to a website when you use the words "Flask" and "HTML". If you don't clear your SQL input, then you'll be open to SQL injection attacks: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection. Normally I'm relatively lax at pointing out security flaws like this because most data science is not public-facing (what queries the programmer puts in are the only ones that ever will be executed). The web is not so safe.

Comment: Oh, yeah I don't have to worry much about that, my boss said just to get the code to work, but I will look into it.